# Kafka rerun capabilities

Tags: apache-kafka

Can we rerun a message from an offset or during a time duration without pooling all the messages? If Yes please let me know. I have tried using Kafka API but its consuming all the messages first then filtering based on the records. My requirement is to send an offset as an input to get the message details or to send From and To date/time interval to fetch the records

Answer (score 0):

You can use kafka's seek api to seek to a specific topicParition offset and consumer message from there

Refer to the api -

`public void seek(TopicPartition partition,long offset)`

Overrides the fetch offsets that the consumer will use on the next poll(timeout). 
If this API is invoked for the same partition more than once, the latest offset will be used on the next poll(). 
Note that you may lose data if this API is arbitrarily used in the middle of consumption, to reset the fetch offsets